# Office 365 MyAnalytics Full vs Workplace analytics

Tags: office365, analytics

I am trying to find documentation that differentiates the two. However I had no luck as they look one of the same. Are these two products the same or are they different? I currently have Business Premium, can I buy the license separate?

Answer (score 0):

Main difference is:

MyAnalytics is your the individual employee data

WorkPlace Analytics is understanding how the organization functions as a whole